# RHadoop - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: rhadoop

Thanks for considering to answer this question.

I am new to RHadoop.

I have installed Hadoop 2.3.0 single node cluster on Windows 7 64 bit machine. I could successfully run map-reduce examples such as pi, wordcount.

Subsequently I successfully installed rhadoop packages rmr-3.0.0 (using rmr2_3.0.0.zip for Windows) and rhdfs-1.0.8 (using rhdfs_1.0.8.zip for Windows) in R version 3.0.2.

Now, when I try to run the simple example (My first Map Reduce Job)described in the RHadoop tutorial, I get errors as described below.

On issuing the command

```
small.ints = to.dfs(1:1000)
```

I get the following message:

14/03/21 19:22:30 WARN zlib.ZlibFactory: Failed to load/initialize native-zlib library
14/03/21 19:22:30 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.deflate]
Warning message:
In to.dfs(1:1000) : Converting to.dfs argument to keyval with a NULL key

However, when I check the result using command

```
from.dfs(small.ints)
```

I get the expected output, indicating that the previous command may have worked successfully. However, I did not understand the Warning about zlib library. Also I do not know how to fix it.

Next, I issued the command

```
mapreduce(input = small.ints, map = function(k, v) cbind(v, v^2))
```

This command did not run successfully and I received a failure message. The log is copied below.

```
14/03/21 19:22:33 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-local-env20e83b74d10, C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-global-env20e8ed94c9d, C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-streaming-map20e8427b46f0, /C:/tmp/hadoop-Admin/hadoop-unjar1983326986611970810/] [] C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\streamjob8826665567257561424.jar tmpDir=null
14/03/21 19:22:34 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/03/21 19:22:34 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
14/03/21 19:22:35 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/03/21 19:22:35 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/03/21 19:22:35 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
14/03/21 19:22:35 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1395405139095_0004
14/03/21 19:22:36 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1395405139095_0004
14/03/21 19:22:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: [http://KALAMKAR:8088/proxy/application_1395405139095_0004/]
14/03/21 19:22:36 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1395405139095_0004
14/03/21 19:22:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1395405139095_0004 running in uber mode : false
14/03/21 19:22:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/21 19:22:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137

14/03/21 19:22:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

14/03/21 19:22:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

14/03/21 19:22:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

14/03/21 19:23:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/03/21 19:23:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

14/03/21 19:23:03 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/21 19:23:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1395405139095_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:222)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Rscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:209)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
        ... 24 more

14/03/21 19:23:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/03/21 19:23:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1395405139095_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1395405139095_0004_m_000001
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

14/03/21 19:23:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 13
        Job Counters 
                Failed map tasks=7
                Killed map tasks=1
                Launched map tasks=8
                Other local map tasks=6
                Data-local map tasks=2
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=32518
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=32518
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=32518
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=33298432
        Map-Reduce Framework
                CPU time spent (ms)=0
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/03/21 19:23:08 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not Successful!
Streaming Command Failed!
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, combine = combine, vectorized.reduce,  : 
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'd:/hadoop-2.3.0/bin/hadoop jar d:/hadoop-2.3.0/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0.jar   -D     "stream.map.input=typedbytes"     -D     "stream.map.output=typedbytes"     -D     "stream.reduce.input=typedbytes"     -D     "stream.reduce.output=typedbytes"     -D     "mapred.reduce.tasks=0"     -input     "\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\file20e85b146fe2"     -output     "\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\file20e81dd3439e"     -mapper     "Rscript ../../jars/rmr-streaming-map20e8427b46f0"     -file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-local-env20e83b74d10 -file C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-global-env20e8ed94c9d   -file     "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpWUxNhy\rmr-streaming-map20e8427b46f0"       -inputformat     "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.AutoInputFormat"     -outputformat     "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileOutputFormat"   2>&1' had status 1 
rm: `UsersAdminAppDataLocalTempRtmpWUxNhyfile20e858f55d2a': No such file or directory
14/03/21 19:23:16 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
Deleted /Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWUxNhy/file20e825892aa8
```

I do not understand how to fix the runtime exceptions that appear in the log.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with the `file`-parameter and a file called `Rscript` is not available to each Hadoop node. Maybe it wasn't put into the job package file. I had a similar problem with a jar-file. Although it was inside the job's library folder it wasn't available to Yarn. So I copied it into a classpath folder of Yarn (`yarn.application.classpath`) and then the job could run.